# How to detect while caps lock is on/off using angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, capslock

I need one help.I have one password filed validation which only takes the special character.At the time of typing password if user is typing any upper case letter the caps lock on notification will display and when it will off the message should display also.Please check my existing code below.

```
<span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px">Password :</span>
<div ng-class="{ 'has-error': billdata.pass.$touched && billdata.pass.$invalid }">
<input type="{{inputType}}" name="pass" id="contactno" class="form-control" placeholder="password" ng-model="password" ng-minlength="8" ng-pattern="/^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z]).*_.*/" >
</div>
</div>
<div class="help-block" ng-messages="billdata.pass.$error" ng-if="billdata.pass.$touched">
<p ng-message="minlength" style="color:#F00;">This field is too short.The min length of your password should be 8.</p>
<p ng-message="pattern" style="color:#F00;">This field needs the special character like at least one number,upper case,lower case letter and underscore.</p>

</div>
```

Please help me to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

this can be done using `ngCapsLock`   module

include relevent js and specify  ngCapsLock as a dependency:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngCapsLock']);
```

then

```
<p class="caps-lock-alert" ng-show='isCapsLockOn'>Caps lock is on</p>
```

[ngCapsLock](http://ngmodules.org/modules/ng-caps-lock)

Comment: I was using but no message was coming.

Comment: are you sure you have included files and specified dependency correctly?

Comment: I have not posted the total code.Let me to create the plunkr.

Comment: you can check [this plunkr link](http://plnkr.co/edit/v398YWLCwy2CNy0hWTiv?p=preview).

Answer (score 1):

Simple library with capslock support.

**Using CapsLock.js**

The current status of the caps lock key can be determined using the isOn function, which returns true if caps lock currently appears to be on and false if it appears to be off:

```
// check the state of the caps lock key
if (CapsLock.isOn()){

  // caps lock is on

}
```

http://code.stephenmorley.org/javascript/detecting-the-caps-lock-key/

Answer (score 0):

For angularJS developers, here's a working example to check if the button is activated or not :

On your JS file :

```
  $scope.checkCase = function(event) {
        var isOn = event.originalEvent.getModifierState('CapsLock');
        if (isOn) {
            console.log('ON');
        }
    };
```

HTML : Add this to your INPUT :

```
 ng-keyup="checkCase($event)"
```